# How to make the gridcolumn have some text in it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I am using a gridcontrol and it is has four columns.  I coded it in such a way that validation occurs when any column field is empty. For that I used `string.empty`.

My problem occurs when the user enters whitespace in the column and saves.  The "empty" text is gets saved and I don't want this to happen. I need the column to have some text before it can be saved.

How can I prevent empty strings from being saved?

Comment: Did u check out whether the cell value is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of string.empty you can first trim() and then apply string.empty.....or you can use regex(regular expressions) to do the validations.... check these links :- [1st Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykdxa0bc.aspx) , [2nd Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ehy30d4%28VS.80%29.aspx)